# Configuring Jest and Enzyme for React app using create-react-app

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, create-react-app, enzyme

I have built a sample React application using create-react-app (CRA), I am trying to write the unit testing for the application.

Using Jest and Enzyme, I have installed the required packages as the dev dependencies

```
    "enzyme": "^3.10.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.15.1",
    "jest": "^24.9.0"
```

**jest.config.js** - located **outside** of **src** folder

```
module.exports = {
    verbose: true,
    setupFilesAfterEnv: ["./src/setupTest.js"],
};
```

**setupTest.js** - located **inside** of **src** folder root

```
import { configure } from "enzyme";
import Adapter from "enzyme-adapter-react-16";

configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });
```

**App.test.js**

```
import React from "react";
import { shallow } from "enzyme";

import App from "./App";

describe("<App />", () => {
    it("Renders the app component", () => {
        const wrapper = shallow(<App />);
        expect(wrapper).toMatchSnapshot();
    });
});
```

When I try to do **npm run test**, it's giving the below error:

```
Enzyme Internal Error: Enzyme expects an adapter to be configured, but found none.
      To configure an adapter, you should call `Enzyme.configure({ adapter: new Adapter() })`
      before using any of Enzyme's top level APIs, where `Adapter` is the adapter
      corresponding to the library currently being tested. For example:

      import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-15';

      To find out more about this, see http://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/installation/index.html

   6 | describe("<App />", () => {
   7 |     it("Renders the app component", () => {
>  8 |         const wrapper = shallow(<App />);
     |                         ^
   9 |         expect(wrapper).toMatchSnapshot();
  10 |     });
  11 | });
```

Comment: Change "setupFilesAfterEnv" to "setupFiles" in your jest config

Comment: thanks for the response , but .. setupFilesAfterEnv ? there is no named file like that

Comment: I meant to say use "setupFiles" configutation instead of "setupFilesAfterEnv" and provide your jest setup file. Use following jest config
module.exports = {
    verbose: true,
    setupFiles: ["<rootDir>/src/setupTest.js"],
};

Comment: can you just post the answer so it will be helpful to update which file

Comment: Sorry I was not helping much I was confused with some jest congfigurations. Can you add a line console.log("some text") in the setupTest.js to see if the adapter configuration is being called? I assume there might be some spelling mistakes or path issues.

Answer (score 4):

You must name your `setupFilesAfterEnv` file as `src/setupTests.js` or `src/setupTests.ts`. This cannot be configured using without ejecting from create-react-app.

Here is a functional setup file for CRA:

### `src/setupTests.js`

(note that it's `setupTests` and not `setupTest` in the file name)

```js
import { configure } from "enzyme";
import Adapter from "enzyme-adapter-react-16";

configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });
```

[More information](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/running-tests/#initializing-test-environment)

Answer (score 0):

I think there is typo in your file name you forgot to add **s** at the end of file name (setupTests), the expected path for your setup file is `src/setupTests.js`.

You can go with this filename also but then you have to include it in the jest config like below.

```
// package.json
{
    ...,
    "jest": {
        "setupFilesAfterEnv": "<rootDir>/test-setup.js"
    }
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: there are two ways either you can refer the file in the package.json or you can create a .js file for holding the config of jest. I have created the file but its not able to sync it. Is it possible can you create a codesandbox with that it will be much more helpful